90's Drama Suspense
So I have been racking my brain and searching for a movie for a over a year now. I'm sick and tired of trying to figure out on my own. Please let me know if you can help. 
Beginning of Movie: 
Has a ranch with a large tree in front yard. Tree has a tire/rope swing. On the farm live a family with one child, a girl. Just before dark the little girl find a boy swinging on the tire. The family invites the boy in for the night. In the middle of the night the boy sneaks down stairs and unlocks the door. Then enters the boy's dad. The dad and son were going to rob the place. The mom and dad of girl wake up and the dad killed them both. 
Rest of Movie:movie flashes forward 10-15 years. Long story short, boy meets girl down the road and the fall in love. Not knowing who each other is. Boy's dad finds out and tries to kill girl. Boy kills dad at the end. 

Just checked it out! You hit the nail in the head! That's it. I have searched and searched as asked all sorts of "movie guru's" etc. and no one had a clue. Hell my wife thought I made it up. I can finally sleep tonight!

Glad to help out!  James Caan definitely had "sinister" turned up to 11 in that one.  (Show your appreciation by marking my answer as the "accepted" answer.  Thanks!)

Sounds like Flesh and Bone, (1993):

Some thirty years after Arlis witnesses his father murdering a family,
  he runs into Kay, who happens to be the family's baby who was spared.
  Kay and Arlis suspect nothing about each other, but when his father
  returns, old wounds are reopened.

